# Bug in the Preview/Display of Wiki Introduction Markdown

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation, markdown-rendering, documentation-intro

I've noticed something strange when I edit the wiki intro of a concept, for instance: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/backbone.js/8178/sync

When editing the intro the preview function displays the processed markdown for lists as expected.  In other words the code:

```
- a
- b
- c
```

correctly becomes three bullet-ted lines.  However, once you save the edit the text is treated as plain text, ie. you get:

```
-a - b - c
```

At the very least this seems like a bug in the preview, but ideally it'd be nice if the wiki intro text could process markdown the same as the rest of the site.

Comment: UH? The specs says that those should be unordered lists. If anything, the render is in the wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

I have a feeling that the underlying issue here has been addressed by now. Saving the draft and reloading it seems to still render the markdown as a list. However, Introduction doesn't allow lists, so on submission I get an error, as expected:

[image]