# Links render as raw markdown in Documentation's "Introduction" section

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation, markdown, hyperlinks

See [this documentation topic](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/8363/concurrent-collections#t=201612231523142860552). The "Introduction" section contains a block of text ("collection") which has markdown to make a it a link to another topic. When viewing the topic, I see the raw markdown:

[image]

When I try to edit the introduction, the rendered version of the text displays as linkified:

[image]

The text editor for the introduction section has the hyperlink button, which implies that linkified text is supposed to work in the introduction section.

Similar to [Links to documentation aren't rendered properly](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329130/links-to-documentation-arent-rendered-properly) but not the same issue. Might be related to [Bug in the Preview/Display of Wiki Introduction Markdown](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339460/bug-in-the-preview-display-of-wiki-introduction-markdown).

Comment: Experienced the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/116571?filter-tags=ios

Comment: Same [here](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/wpf/8365/wpf-behaviors#t=201704231837234770224); but if you use `[link](http://example.com)` it works correctly as [here](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/79/string-format#t=201704231849032455687)

Answer (score 3):

Introductions support a limited set of markdown, to prevent it from growing too large (pushing examples too far down the page).

There were some bugs in validation and rendering in those restrictions.

As of the latest build, Introduction will correctly enforce restrictions (no images, no lists, no tables) and render `[1]`-style links correctly.

The editor buttons for elements that are not supported are also removed.  Working on getting the preview pane ignoring them as well (that's a trickier change).

Comment: So, this is supposed to be fixed, but the [page in question](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/8363/concurrent-collections#t=201702171622442485806) still displays raw markdown. Does something else need to be done?